# canvas не работает в условии в функции

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
alert("5");
var xax = 200;
var example = document.getElementById("example"),
  ctx = example.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 150);
ctx.strokeRect(250, 100, 200, 30);
ctx.fillRect(250, 100, xax, 20);
window.onload = function() {
  example.addEventListener("mousedown", onDown, false);
};

function onDown(event) {
  cx = event.pageX;
  cy = event.pageY;



  alert("X,Y=" + cx + "," + cy);
  if (cx > 50 && cx < 150 && cy < 200 && cy > 50) {
    alert("кнопка");
  }
};
```

```html
<canvas height='1280' width='720' id='example'>Обновите браузер</canvas>
```

Я относительно недавно начал изучать `js, html и css`, поэтому вопросов очень много, а ответов - чуть меньше.

После нажатия кнопки срабатывает функция `onDown(event)`, появляется `alert()` с координатами позиции мышки, где был произведен клик, и если нажатие было в рамках `fillRect(50, 50, 100, 150)`, то выводится ещё один `alert` с сообщением ***кнопка***. Хотелось бы ещё вместо `alert("кнопка")` уменьшать переменную ***xax*** на ***19***, чтобы уменьшалась длинна `fillRect` с этой переменной. Но, в данном месте, допустим после ***32*** строки, чтобы я с `canvas-ом` не делал, никаких изменений на выходе не вижу. Как можно реализовать данную задумку?

Comment: Вам просто нужно уменьшить значение `xax` на 19, я правильно понял?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич, "Хотелось бы ещё вместо alert("кнопка") уменьшать переменную xax на 19, чтобы уменьшалась длинна fillRect с этой переменной". Да, мне надо уменьшать 'xax' на 19, чтобы уменьшался и fillRect с этой переменной вместо длинны. Переменная может и уменьшается, а вот 'fillRect' - нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну я так понял вы это имели в виду. Не знаю в таком случае, в чем сложность.

```js
    // alert("5");
var xax = 200;

window.onload = function() {
  example.addEventListener("mousedown", onDown, false);
};
var example = document.getElementById("example");
 var ctx = example.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 150);
 ctx.strokeRect(250, 100, 200, 30);
 ctx.fillRect(250, 100, xax, 20);

function onDown(event) {
  cx = event.pageX;
  cy = event.pageY;
 

 ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 150);
 ctx.strokeRect(250, 100, 200, 30);
 ctx.fillRect(250, 100, xax, 20);
  // alert("X,Y=" + cx + "," + cy);
  if (cx > 50 && cx < 150 && cy < 200 && cy > 50) {
    // alert("кнопка");
     xax = xax - 19;
  }
 console.log(xax);
}
```

```html
<canvas height='1280' width='720' id='example'>Обновите браузер</canvas>
```

Comment: В этом сложности нет, верно. Но 'fillRect' с переменной 'xax' не уменьшается, а остаётся прежним. Об этом и мой вопрос.

Comment: @Lekury исправил, все оказалось куда проще.

Comment: @Lekury не уверен валидно ли это, но изменил!

Comment: Все то же самое, изменений в 'fillRect' нет.

Comment: @Lekury а вы до минуса дошли, ?

Comment: Дошёл, переменная меняется, длинна 'fillRect' - нет

Comment: У меня все меняется в этом примере. Вы хотели изменение переменной и длинны. У меня открыв этот написанный мною код - работает.

Comment: Да, теперь вижу, после 0 длина увеличивается. Но идея не в этом - длина должна уменьшаться до нуля, т.е. в условие надо добавить ещё одно значение: 'if (cx > 50 && cx < 150 && cy < 200 && cy > 50 && xax > 0) {
    // alert("кнопка");
     xax = xax - 19;
  }' Но длина ведь не уменьшается, а только увеличивается после 0

Comment: @Lekury Ну возможно идея была не в это, но мне кажется это тема уже другого вопроса)

Comment: Идею я описал, и именно про неё этот вопрос - ***Хотелось бы ещё вместо 'alert("кнопка")' уменьшать переменную 'xax' на 19, чтобы уменьшалась длинна 'fillRect' с этой переменной. *** :)